# Database normalization with multi table query

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I'm trying to create a site related to recipes where users can add custom meals, and within meals they can add foods and then list the ingredients of the foods. For example:

```
Meal = Dinner
Food = Hamburger
Ingredient = Tomato
```

Users can select foods from a pre-filled database of food items. They can also add ingredients from a central ingredients database. So the same food and ingredient ids can be used by any user of the site.

The challenge I have is ensuring the food_has_ingredients table is linked to the user somehow. In the diagram below the meal is associated to the user. Since the foods and ingredients ids can be re-used by multiple users I can't rely on those ids to determine which user adds ingredients to a food.

Take this example:

```
User 1 adds the food "hamburger" (id 10) to the meal_has_food table, then associates the ingredients "ketchup" (id 20) to the food_has_ingredients table.
User 2 adds the food "hamburger" (id 10) to the meal_has_food table, then associates the ingredients "pickles" (id 21) to the food_has_ingredients table.
```

If someone does a search get all ingredients from the meal hamburger (10) and limit it to one row, it would always give the first person's entry. So I've associated the meal id as a foreign key that way I can say get the ingredient for hamburger that belongs to meal id X.

I'd like to know if that makes sense or if there's a better way.

Here's a rough db schema:
[image: Database schema]

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: What is the functionality you are missing that you want? As far as I can tell that does what you intend it to.

Comment: Woz not sure, possibly? I've never visited that site.

Comment: Ignacio, as far as I can tell it seems fine. However I've been speaking to other programming friends and they seemed confused why the meals_id would be in the food_has_ingredient table. They felt that wasn't required.

Either I was missing something obvious or my assumptions on structure were correct. So I figured I'd get more opinions on the matter.

Comment: If 2 meals can have the same food with 2 different sets of ingredients, then you need some way to represent that. What you did is one way of doing so. The table name might be a bit misleading, but I can't think of another obvious way to do this off the top of my head.